# i need to make a button that opens a custom dialogbox

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, dialog

I'm creating an android app for my school project.

I created the interface normaly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/mappic"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ZoomControls
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Obtenir le PCC"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now I want to make it when I click on the button : Obtenir le PCC this dialog box opens up :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff7518ff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Suivantbtn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Suivantbtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Suivantbtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textdp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Taper le poit de départ:"
        android:textColor="#ff111124"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Suivantbtn"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp" />/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Suivantbtn"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suivant "
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Suivantbtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textdp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textdp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textdp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textdp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff9eadff" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and when I click on Suivant ,, the dialog box goes and another dialogbox appears :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff7518ff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Suivantbtn2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Suivantbtn2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Suivantbtn2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Taper le poit d'arrivée:"
        android:textColor="#ff111124"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Suivantbtn2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp" />/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Suivantbtn2"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suivant "
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Suivantbtn2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textar"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff9eadff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the java code :

```
package artofdev.org.admaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Suivantbtn);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
                    Button button3 = (Button) 
  dialog2.findViewById(R.id.Suivantbtn2);
                    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    dialog2.show();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And when this appears and I type in and click on next. This dialog box dismisses and another msg box I'll create later shows a msg.

how to do it ?

Comment: You need to set onClickListener to the button http://www.howtosolvenow.com/2013/11/android-button-setonclicklistener-example/

Comment: first learn some java and android programming - there are many tutorials in internet, and then write questions that are NOT answered many times here or just learn how to search in Google....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully working code for you:

```
Context context = getAplicationContext();
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
        Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Suivantbtn);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
                dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.your_second_dialog_layout);
                Button button3 = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.Suivantbtn2);
                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog2.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog2.show();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Hope my answer helped!

Comment: i have something concering the : context it's like an error

Comment: add this in the beginning of your code: `Context context = getAplicationContext();`

Comment: Can you share the whole code of your java file? @DhiaaRebbah

Comment: and also the @overide up the public void onclick function : it says : annotations are not allowed here

Comment: @DhiaaRebbah please copy paste your code to this site: http://pastebin.com and share the link of your code.

Comment: iam such a bigginer in java and android ,, it's just for my school project lol ,, but i'm comming yeah sure ^^

Comment: they said : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: just email me : dhiaarebbah@gmail.com and we can talk sir pleaaase

Comment: i can't answer you sir :(

Comment: nothing :/ i can see your msgs but i can't answer you

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //do something - for example open the dialog box you want
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialogue);
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add `onClickListener` to your buttons. For example (this code is for your Activity class):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //do something - for example open the dialog box you want
    }
});
```